# loop executes only once with pointer assignment

Tags: c

I have a simple code to reverse a string:

```
char* reverse(char* s){    
int i,j,len=strlen(s);
char* r;


for(i=len-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++){
    printf("%d:%c\n",j,s[i]);
    r[j]=s[i];
}
```

assume input string is "abc" , then the output "Without" the line `r[j]=s[i];` inside loop is :

```
0:c
1:b
2:a
```

if I include the `r[j]=s[i]` assignment, output stops at it!

```
0:c
```

Why the assignment stops the loop here?

Comment: Run your debugger. Or just think about it.

Comment: `char* r;` Where do you think `r` points to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are writing to uninitialized pointer: char* r is declared, but never allocated. Allocate memory dynamically or on the stack, then write into it.
For example:

```
char* r = malloc(len + 1);
```

Right now your code is most likely crashing when you are trying to access uninitialized memory.

Comment: As I said, allocate memory. If you are limioted to c, then do char* r = (char*)malloc(len+1); And don't forget to free it when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

A few things are causing problems...

j is being assigned to zero and compared to zero in the for loop which will immediately satisfy the condition of the loop and it will exit.

Also note that the string length will be reported for 1 less than the real size due to the fact that arrays include 0 as the first element so sizes are always one less then what's in the array.

I'd recommend pulling j out of the for loop assignment and increment it within the body of the loop itself. It will be easier to debug and you can put a watch on it's value and step through the code.

```
// an example of how to assign the input value for a
// function accepting an array of characters instead of a pointer
char s[] ="hellodude";

// start of the function which accepts an array of char
// (may need adjusting to return a buffer and pointer
// etc. you can determine that)
char* reverse(char s[]){
    // note the following changes to fix the iterating problems...
    int i,j=0,len=strlen(s)+1;
    char r[len];

    for(i=len-1,i>=0;i--;){
        j++;
        printf("%d:%c\n",j,s[i]);
        r[j]=s[i];
    }
return r;
}
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.